# android SqliteDatabase Error: inserting column values

Tags: android

i am making an app in which i need to save some values to the `sqlitedatabase` for that purpose i wrote this function

```
public long saveMood(Mood mood) {
        openDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_ACTIVE, (mood.isActive() ? 1 : 0));
        cv.put(COL_BLOCK_CALL, (mood.isBlockCall() ? 1 : 0));
        cv.put(COL_BLOCK_CALL, (mood.isBlockCall() ? 1 : 0));
        cv.put(COL_BLOCK_SMS, (mood.isBlockSms() ? 1 : 0));
        cv.put(COL_SILENT, (mood.isSilent() ? 1 : 0));
        cv.put(COL_VIBRATE, (mood.isVibrate() ? 1 : 0));
        cv.put(COL_WIFI, (mood.isWifiOn() ? 1 : 0));
        cv.put(COL_TIME, mood.getTime());
        cv.put(COL_NAME, mood.getName());
        cv.put(COL_VOLUME, mood.getRingVolumn());
        long id = database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        closeDatabase();
        return id;
    }
```

And the query i used to create my table is this

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME 
                    + "("
                    + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " 
                    + COL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                    + COL_ACTIVE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_BLOCK_CALL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_BLOCK_SMS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_BRIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_SILENT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_TIME + " LONG NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_VIBRATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_VOLUME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COL_WIFI + " INTEGER NOT NULL "
                    + " ); ";
```

but i am gettings this exception each time with insert id = -1

```
 Error inserting silent=1 call_block=1 time=0 wifi=0 name=night volume=0 sms_block=1 vibrate=0 active=0
08-19 11:09:05.790: E/Database(6648):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1658)
08-19 11:09:05.790: E/Database(6648):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1519)
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things seems wrong here

**First**

```
COL_BRIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
```

is  NOT NULL but you did not provide a value for this in `saveMood` method. So this is the reason for `Conflict`

***Solution***

Provide a value for `COL_BRIGHT` or remove  `NOT NULL`

**Second**

This seems to  a repeat of lines

```
cv.put(COL_BLOCK_CALL, (mood.isBlockCall() ? 1 : 0));
cv.put(COL_BLOCK_CALL, (mood.isBlockCall() ? 1 : 0));
```

***Solution***

Remove the repeated line

Comment: Thanks! That Was my Error

Answer (score 1):

All columns have a `not  null` constraint. But the error log shows:

```
silent=1 call_block=1 time=0 wifi=0 name=night volume=0 sms_block=1 vibrate=0 active=0
```

Which means, values for `volume` and `bright` are missing, SQLite won't accept this insert as table requires all record values to be not null.

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Remove NOT NULL keyword in Primary key of Create Query thats because the primary key with autoincreament would not be null in any case
Or Else Use insertWithOnConflict() method instead of insert() method